# Android Studio - Resource Entry already defined

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

After compiling my Android application using the Android Studio (Beta), I have the following error:

```
Error:error: Resource entry background is already defined.
res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\background.9.png:0: Originally defined here.
```

This occurred when I had a image file called "background" in my res folder.

I then made a 9 patch version of it and pasted it in the same folder. This meant that there was 2 files with the same name. So I unsurprisingly I had this error.

However I now deleted all instances of the background image file (including the 9 patch version and original image) in my code and layout file and I still have this error.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You could try to do one of the following:

- Clean and Build or `gradle clean build assemble`
- Invalidate and restart Android Studio

Comment: Thank you so much! I was looking for a command like this, but didn't know where to look as eclipse is slightly different. Didn't think it will be with the gradle.

Comment: Also what is "Invalidate"?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: The "Invalidate" part is an AndroidStudio/IntelliJ specific function. It's under File > Invalidate Caches/ Restart. What it does is basically "refresh" the state of your IDE, sort of doing a reboot so it would reinitialize some items again.

Answer (score 16):

1 **Build > Clean Project** 
2 **Build > Rebuild Project**

Answer (score 9):

I am using Android studio and I run exactly into the same issue and none of the answers I found on the web helped me solve the problem, including the previous one. So reading through all details of the error messages and found this lines:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>       C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio\sdk\build-tools\android-4.4W\aapt.exe package -f --no-crunch -I C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio\sdk\platforms\android-20\android.jar -M C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\DartsApp\app\build\intermediates\manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml -S C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\DartsApp\app\build\intermediates\res\debug -A C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\DartsApp\app\build\intermediates\assets\debug -m -J C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\DartsApp\app\build\generated\source\r\debug -F C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\DartsApp\app\build\intermediates\libs\app-debug.ap_ --debug-mode --custom-package com.dartstransit.dartsapp -0 apk --output-text-symbols C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\DartsApp\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug

Error Code:

```
1
```

Output:

```
res\drawable-hdpi-v4\bus_w.png:0: error: Resource entry bus_w is already defined.
res\drawable-hdpi-v4\bus_w.jpg:0: Originally defined here.
```

As you can see there are two files of name bus_w with different extensions on the same folder. I had already removed those files from the project and still getting the error, so I decided to check every single folder of the project that was reference in the compiler line in the error message. Finally found that there was a copy of the file bus_w.png in the folder `app\build\intermediates\res\debug\drawable-mdpi-v4`.

I just deleted it and voila, problem solved.

Comment: This worked for me in AS 1.0 after trying the accepted answer had failed.

Comment: Well that helps. Deleted the temp build directory and my error was gone.

Answer (score 3):

A simple **Build** > **Rebuild project** helped me

Answer (score 1):

Did you try rename this file to other name? It seem one of your libraries have same resource.

I see that many devs(include me) had issue with `ic_launcher` too. I think you want to try `mipmap` instead `drawable`. So we will have something like this:

```
\res\mipmap-hdpi
\res\mipmap-mdpi
\res\mipmap-xhdpi
\res\mipmap-xxhdpi
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

I have also encountered this error recently.Here is my solution that works,hope it will help you.

1.only keep 9 patch version image in the drawable-hdpi folder

2.make sure the code related to this problem in xml file remains the same:     `android:background="@drawable/msg_left"`

instead of using the code:

`android:background="@drawable/msg_left.9"`

PS:My original image name is msg_left,and my 9 patch version image name is msg_left.9

Answer (score 0):

I did the trick by moving the icon

```
drawable/ic_launcher
```

to

```
mipmap/ic_launcher
```

and it worked fine :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was that I had more than one '.' in the filename. like:

```
a.png
a.bold.png
```

Solution was to rename to

```
a.png
a_bold.png
```

Answer (score 0):

In our case, problem started occurring (error shows 'duplicate value for resource' in a library) when some other library was upgraded to it's latest version.
We just downgraded the version of the library that was upgraded.

Real pain was because that we have many dependencies which can be dynamically upgraded when there is a new version available in repositories. So my teammate had to go through all libs that can be dynamically upgraded and see if there is one that is recently upgraded, try to downgrade it and check if build goes fine. He identified many were upgraded on previous day. Downgrading one of them got the build back.

Conclusion we made is not to use Dynamic Versioning. [Don't use dynamic versions for your dependencies](https://blog.danlew.net/2015/09/09/dont-use-dynamic-versions-for-your-dependencies/).

This was the error by the way:

> > Task :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> >     AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"error: duplicate value for resource \u0027attr/itemBackground\u0027 with config \u0027\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"/Users/unknownuser/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/singledateandtimepicker-1.2.2.aar/86ae3786d70c769e610c8a01d58aa638/res/values/values.xml","position":{"startLine":15,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":2427,"endColumn":48,"endOffset":2471}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
> >     AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"error: resource previously defined here.","sources":[{"file":"/Users/unknownuser/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/singledateandtimepicker-1.2.2.aar/86ae3786d70c769e610c8a01d58aa638/res/values/values.xml","position":{"startLine":15,"startColumn":4,"startOffset":2427,"endColumn":48,"endOffset":2471}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}
>
> Task :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
>   Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.